# Visual Studio Community 2019 C++ Console App template closes instantly

Tags: c++, visual-studio, console

**Edit:1** There have been a lot of good suggestions to help me out. The answer by Jeaninez has helped my Hello World stay on the screen instead of blinking for a microsecond.

But my initial question stands, why does Visual Studio 2019 default Hello World Console App not hold the Hello World open and instead open two windows. Here is a video with the fixed version and the one with the default template: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LVUsHp9K8Tw

*Original Question*
I'm sure this question has been asked a million times, but my issue seems to be quite different. I am using the 
[Console App Template](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5JL4z.jpg) which is by default a hello world, but when I Ctrl+F5 it to see how it works it blinks on the screen then shows this:

[image]

I tried putting in a `return 0;` and made sure my project was set to Console. The only thing that I've found that helps a tiny bit is `system("pause");

Comment: Seems to be working largely as expected, except that the window is so tiny that your program's output is scrolled away...? Have you tried resizing the window?

Comment: thank you for responding and yes, I tried resizing it. and it says "ted with code 0.
Press any key to close this window . . ."

Comment: I think you might have to find a way to stop it opening so small in the first place. But it's also hard to rule out other factors without a [mcve] (or any detail shown)

Comment: Put a break point on the last line in main and then run it with debugging.  What do you get then?

Comment: I put a breakpoint in the last line in Main and ran it with debugging and it worked! Here's my question, but why? Why did the default console app need a breakpoint to work? Shouldn't a hello world template work by default?

Comment: As I said, it does work. The breakpoint "froze" the program at the point before the "closing window" text came along. You froze time. Now, using Kate's instructions, you can make it so that the appearance of the "closing window" text doesn't hide your program's output later on.

Answer (score 3):

It's not closing. You know that - you took a picture of it.

It is, however, really small. And in addition VS 2019 (unlike earlier versions) adds this text about "press any key" to close the window. So you're not seeing your own output at all.

Here's what to do. Click the little icon in the title bar:
[image]

You will get a menu, choose Properties. This gets you a tabbed dialog: choose Layout. Change to a larger height and width and you'll be able to see what is going on.

When you like it, after you have finished running the app and closed the console window, close Visual Studio and re-open it. Now you'll consistently get that window size.

Comment: Ah, right - 'twas the "resolution" setting I was missing. Cheers, cmd.exe!

Comment: While I appreciate your help on figuring out the sizing of the window. This is not at all my issue. The hello world blinks for split second before it disappears and shows that last window. ATM, I i'm not concerned with the size of the window. I've made a video to demonstrate my issue. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=e8dd5Zbn-

Comment: you have TWO console windows? one that goes away and this one? And you're just using the default code that was generated for you? Your video link doesn't work, and I find this really hard to imagine.

Comment: whoops, I copied the link incorrectly https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=e8dd5Zbn-Jw and yes I have two windows.

Comment: can you make the (second) window bigger anyway? that will make it obvious when the little one goes away and the big one appears, or if what's happening is the text in the single tiny window is changing.

Comment: I can but it's not as important as trying to figure out why the window disappears instantly despite a "system("pause");" Also yes it is two windows.

Comment: I couldn't reproduce your issue on Windows system with vs2019.Can you provide detailed steps to reproduce the issue?
"system("pause");" is part of Windows API and so it won't work in other operation systems.You should try to use just objects from C++ standard library. I suggest you could try to use "cin.get(); return 0;"

Comment: Remove the pause call and use F5 to run, not Ctrl-F5. Also *please* make your console bigger (in console properties).

Comment: The correct answer was provided to me by Jeaninez! Thank you that did it. To everyone else who keeps thinking it was my window size... that was incorrect. Regarding my window size is another matter that no matter what I do, it stays that size. I've even gone into my registry to try to fix it to no avail. Thank you Jeaninez! Can someone please mark Jeaninez's answer as the correct one?

Comment: comments can't be marked as correct answers. Also, there should be no need for `cin.get()` -- Visual Studio now holds the window open. I believe if you could make your window bigger you would see what was happening, but if you're happy with your current situation that's great, that's what we're here for.

Comment: Kate Gregory, once again, I appreciate your advice but the window size literally has nothing to do with my current issue. here's a new video I just made to show you: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LVUsHp9K8Tw

Answer (score 0):

"system("pause");" is part of Windows API and so it won't work in other operation systems.You should try to use just objects from C++ standard library. I suggest you could try to use :

```
    std::cin.get(); 
    return 0;
```